# Can Perforce remove a version entry (like ClearCase Destroy)?

Tags: perforce

I submitted a Changelist in Perforce, but I forgot to remove a couple of files from the list first.  I want to undo those changes.  I understand that Perforce allows me to "rollback" -- but that just submits another change to the file, cluttering my branch.  This is a file I did not intend to change at all.  When I go to integrate back into the baseline, this file shows up as needing to be integrated (even though it's the same as what's on the baseline).

In Clearcase, I had the ability to simply issue a "destroy" command on the specific version of the file, nuking it from the repository, as if had never been (yes, I realize this is scary from a revision control perspective - I understand the risks).

Is there an equivalent command in Perforce?  Or am I trying to do something expressly forbidden?

Comment: Obliterate should only be used as a command of last resort. If it's only a couple of files it's hardly "cluttering" your branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Perforce `obliterate`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/obliterate.html#1040665)** should be a good equivalent for **[`cleartool rmver`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rmver.htm)**

```
p4 obliterate -y file#3,5
```

> Obliterate revisions 3, 4, and 5 of file.
>
> If #5 was the head revision, the new head revision is now #2, and the next revision will be #3.
>   If #5 was not the head revision, the head revision remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Perforce does allow super-users to destroy revisions.  Horrible, horrible idea.  I don't see why you can't just rollback.

Comment: Sometimes, maybe for legal reasons, you *really* don't want files to ever have been in your repository. Or maybe you accidentally checked in a really big file. In general, though, rolling back is the correct thing to do.